How to set variable type when the variable has huge generic type in TypeScript?
I am a fan of script languages and was using javascript for long time. But for a new project I decided to see how ts may help my development or maintaining part of the project. My biggest problem atm is finding types. Let me give an example. I am using drizzle for orm. For some reason I need to store the findMany query config. To be more clear I am pasting the whole type of the findMany function and class here.
export declare class RelationalQueryBuilder<TSchema extends TablesRelationalConfig, TFields extends TableRelationalConfig> {
    private fullSchema;
    private schema;
    private tableNamesMap;
    private table;
    private tableConfig;
    private dialect;
    private session;
    static readonly [entityKind]: string;
    constructor(fullSchema: Record<string, unknown>, schema: TSchema, tableNamesMap: Record<string, string>, table: PgTable, tableConfig: TableRelationalConfig, dialect: PgDialect, session: PgSession);
    findMany<TConfig extends DBQueryConfig<'many', true, TSchema, TFields>>(config?: KnownKeysOnly<TConfig, DBQueryConfig<'many', true, TSchema, TFields>>): PgRelationalQuery<BuildQueryResult<TSchema, TFields, TConfig>[]>;
    findFirst<TSelection extends Omit<DBQueryConfig<'many', true, TSchema, TFields>, 'limit'>>(config?: KnownKeysOnly<TSelection, Omit<DBQueryConfig<'many', true, TSchema, TFields>, 'limit'>>): PgRelationalQuery<BuildQueryResult<TSchema, TFields, TSelection> | undefined>;
}

So let say I have my own class and I want a function that accepts exact same config type. I mean I cant just copy and paste the config type from findMany function. How can I do that ? What I should use for config type in my own function ?
Another question is while using findMany function I am not passing any type. For example :
await db.query.example.findMany({
    where: (posts, { eq }) => (eq(posts.id, 1)),
});

What I expect here is something like this :
await db.query.example.findMany<SomeTypeHere>({
    where: (posts, { eq }) => (eq(posts.id, 1)),
});

Since I am not passing any type what exactly going on here ? How it identifies the generic type ?
My last question is that let say I have a class and a method that accepting the config object. And inside the class I want to store the config value that passed to the function. What is the type of the variable ?
So anyone can provide a basic class that has a single config attribute and a function that accepts config parameter and sets it to class variable (Ofc with proper types)?
I think it should not be that hard. What I am missing here ?

• Please [edit] this to ask a single primary question, or it risks being closed with "Needs more focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only." • Please edit your code to be a [mre] that people can copy and paste into their own IDEs to immediately get to work on it; undeclared private/third-party types or values should be declared for us, or even better, replaced with built in things. Right now if I look at your code example in an IDE I get lots of errors unrelated to the question.

it is actually asking a single question. It may seem like I am asking few but they all actually ask for a class that has a variable and a function and how to set their types. I just break it into few questions  to expalin better.

Even if it only seems like you're asking multiple question then it still risks being closed, so you should still [edit] to make it clear that you're asking a single well-defined question whose scope is appropriately narrow to be good for Stack Overflow.

If I understood you well, I think you are trying to do something like storing the type in a variable like property to reuse it, and you are wondering how should this be implemented.
also to create a class that have one property with this custom reusable type, and how should it be accepted as a function property
type Custom<TConfig, TFields, TSchema> = KnownKeysOnly<
  TConfig,
  DBQueryConfig<"many", true, TSchema, TFields>
>;

class TestClass<TConfig, TFields, TSchema> {
  public config: Custom<TConfig, TFields, TSchema>;
  constructor(config: Custom<TConfig, TFields, TSchema>) {
    this.config = config;
  }

  public takeConfig(config: Custom<TConfig, TFields, TSchema>) {
    this.config = config;
  }
}

const test = new TestClass({
  mode: "many",
  logging: true,
  schema: {},
  fields: {},
});

test.takeConfig({
  mode: "value",
  logging: false,
  schema: {},
  fields: {},
});


  findMany<TConfig extends DBQueryConfig<"many", true, TSchema, TFields>>(
    config?: Custom<TConfig, TFields, TSchema>
  ): PgRelationalQuery<BuildQueryResult<TSchema, TFields, TConfig>[]>;

Here I created the Custom type which takes the TConfig property, as The TConfig property is generic and needs to be provided
If you need more explanation let me know, I just want to confirm this is the answer you are seeking

Thank you for your time but I think there are some missing information I need to provide. First of all if you check RelationalQueryBuilder class TFields is coming from the class generic types. So I cant really declare the tpye as you did in your example. Btw it does not need to be a abstract class. I am going to use it directly.

@ali.turan I edited the original response see if it fits your needs, an error would be returned if you pass the wrong params to takeConfig function,  I dont know drizzle or how it works tried to solve the typescript problems as you described hope that help :)
